# Rspec printed string not flushed

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm discovering RSpec tests which I apply for my ruby code (see [falkorlib](https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib) yet I noticed that the way string are displayed do not follow the sequential order of the instruction.

For instance for this kind of test (extracted from [`spec/falkorlib/git_spec.rb`](https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib/blob/devel/spec/falkorlib/git_spec.rb):

```
describe FalkorLib::Git do

    before :all do
    $stdout.sync = true
    end 

    [...]

    it "#command? - check availability of git command 'init'" do
       c = FalkorLib::Git.command?('init')
       c.should be_true
    end

    it "#submodules_init" do
       FalkorLib.config.git do |c|
          c[:submodules] = {
             'falkorgit' => {
                 :url    => 'https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib.git',
                 :branch => 'devel'
             }
          }
       end
       b = FalkorLib::Git.submodule_init( dir )
       b.should == 0
    end
end
```

The `FalkorLib::Git.submodule_init` produces some output text (flushed) which is printed **before** the text introduced by the `it` call:

```
    [...]
    #command? - check availability of git command 'init'
    [Running]                 ------------------------ text produced by the call to submodule_init
   git submodule init
   git submodule update

   [INFO] Adding Git submodule '.submodules/falkorgit' from 'https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib.git'
   [Running]
   git submodule add -b devel https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib.git .submodules/falkorgit
   git commit -s -m "Add Git submodule '.submodules/falkorgit' from 'https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib.git'" .gitmodules .submodules/falkorgit

Cloning into '.submodules/falkorgit'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 380, done.
remote: Counting objects: 62, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
remote: Total 442 (delta 29), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (442/442), 80.15 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (229/229), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[master 5655ff9] Add Git submodule '.submodules/falkorgit' from 'https://github.com/Falkor/falkorlib.git'
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 .submodules/falkorgit
    #submodules_init             -------------------- the text of it "#submodule_init"
```

Any hint to flush correctly ?
As you see, I tries to force the flush before all tasks, without success so far.